# httpmessagecontent in mvc api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I return `datetime` when using the method `httpmessagecontent`
(I'm building a site which recieves and returns to android studio.)
Here's the code of my function:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpMessageContent TurnDetails(string ServiceName)
{
    int a = db.Sessions.Where(k => k.Service.Description == ServiceName).Count();
    var r = db.Services.Where(l => l.Description == ServiceName).Select((l => l.SessionLength));
    var f = db.Services.Where(k => k.Description == ServiceName).Select(k => k.Openinghours.Select(p => p.OpenTime));
    a = a * Convert.ToInt32(r) + Convert.ToInt32(f);
    Convert.ToDateTime(a);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
return Convert.ToDateTime(a);
```

?

`Convert.ToDateTime` does not modify the supplied parameter in place.  You have to use the value returned from the function.